# Could animals in Eden eat from the tree of life and what would happen to them?

Tags: parashat-bereishit, trees, gan-eden

Following ["*Could animals in Eden eat from the tree of life*"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/121333/could-animals-in-eden-eat-the-forbidden-fruit-of-knowledge-and-what-would-happen),

Could animals in Eden eat from the tree of life and what would happen to them?

Answer (score -3):

If we accept that man evolved from animals, and in a sense, is both human and animal, it would seem that animals were also barred from eating the tree of life. On the other hand, if we accept that Adam was the first to possess a soul, even though animals also have souls but not to the same degree as man, it could be assumed that this was only a human-oriented command.